# angular 5 httpClient and Promises

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've been looking at Angular 5's GET POST etc:

```
get() {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>('https://api.github.com/users/seeschweiler');
}
```

or

```
http.get<ItemsResponse>('/api/items')
    .subscribe(
       // Successful responses call the first callback.
       data => {...},
       // Errors will call this callback instead:
       err => {
         console.log('Something went wrong!');
       });
```

I don't see that promises are usually used with it.

Is this because it's not really needed or some other reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular by defaults uses [**Observables**](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html). Observables give you more flexibility working with streams.

If you want to work with Promises you can still cast Observable into Promises by using `toPromise` function.

Comment: toPromise() is now deprecated - please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

### February 2024

`toPromise()` function call [is now deprecated](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise) and we should be using [firstValueFrom()](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise#firstvaluefrom) or [lastValueFrom()](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise#lastvaluefrom) like so:

```
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

return lastValueFrom(this.httpClient.get<any>(url));
```

returns a promise